# SQL Server : how to interrupt a SQL query halfway?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a few hundred thousand records into my table in SQL Server. I want to simulate a database recovery and to do so, I need to "interrupt" the execution during the insert process. I am using transactions to begin and commit the insert batch by batch. Let's say I committed 20k records and would like to begin transaction for another 20k records, I would like to interrupt the transaction during this second batch insertion.

I am aware of terminating the execution but it just stops the execution and records will still be inserted. It doesn't crash it in any way. I need to make sure when I interrupt the transaction, it doesn't end up being committed to the database.

Is there any way I could do so?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to kill the process? Should do the trick. Otherwise, find the big red button.

Comment: @TomC The big red button just terminates the process. Does it actually rollback the entire process if it doesn't get committed?

Comment: Simple solution is to use Transaction and rollback base on condition(including TRY CATCH).otherwise we want to know why you want to take such drastic step.May be you should use WAIT Delay too

Comment: How are you inserting the records, individually or with a batch approach (e.g. INSERT TableA SELECT FROM Table B).   Without an explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION, each individual INSERT is considered an implicit transaction and is commited as the statement is executed. Therefore if it crashes, any INSERTS before then are valid and never rolled back.   As @KumarHarsh mentions, using a explicit transaction and aborting during the transaction will put you in a recovery situation.

Comment: I am using Begin and Commit transaction to insert records, batch by batch. I want to commit say 20k records first, then begin transaction for another 20k records but during this process, I want to interrupt it.

Comment: Sorry @Daredevil I meant the big red button on the front of the machine. Was being flippant. But as the other comments are saying, if you have started a transaction then abort it, the rows are NOT written. If you get to the commit, then they are. Simple as that. Not sure what sort of recovery you are trying to test. Perhaps you can elaborate.

Comment: @TomC Okay I understand what you meant. I did a test run, rows are not written if it's stopped before committed. Weird thing I noticed is if I try to select count from the table, the execution doesn't complete at all, it goes on forever. Is this a bug?

Comment: Now we have to fully understand data is coming from which source and what like variable or xml or Table Type.At a time how many rows of data is receive to PROC.It is purely coding problem.I ask this much because I will decide at which layer or point to interrupt then continue.

Comment: @Daredevil check if there re any locks, you may find that your process is in a rollback state and/or id blocking your second process. run sp_who2 to check locks.

Comment: @TomC Did a second try, no bug this time. So in other words, SQL server automatically rollback the transaction if the insert process is not committed?

Comment: Yes @Daredevil that is the whole idea of a transaction. Either all or none of the rows get written.

Comment: @TomC Wouldn't it be better to use implicit transaction where each row is inserted one by one and committed straight, to prevent database corruption and minimizing loss of records?

Comment: No, that would be unnecessary as each update or insert statement is automatically wrapped in a transaction anyway. If each batch is a single insert statement then you don't have to do anything. I think you are trying to solve a problem that the database does for you for free. If you use transactions, or its a single statement anyway, then you wont get database corruptions, and you wont lose data as you know if the transaction and therefore all rows got updated or not.

Comment: @TomC I think I didn't explain clearly on my question. Without using transaction, I could just insert the records normally so if anything were to happen in mid process, at least some of the rows are definitely committed to the table right?  Wouldn't this way be better considering by using transaction, either ALL records are inserted or none at all. ?

Comment: Entirely up to you. As long as you know which rows are updated and which are not then its up to you. There is no "Better" answer, just depends on your requirements. "at least some of the records will be written" doesnt *sound* like a good position to be in to me.

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware of terminating the execution but it just stops the
>   execution and records will still be inserted. It doesn't crash it in
>   any way. I need to make sure when I interrupt the transaction, it
>   doesn't end up being committed to the database.

This is wrong.
If you interrupt the `INSERT`, it will be rolled back.
Here is the repro:

```
create table dbo.nums(n bigint not null);
go

insert into dbo.nums 
select row_number() over (order by getdate()) as n
from sys.columns c1 cross join sys.columns c2 cross join sys.columns c3;
```

If you interrupt this code and execute

```
select * from dbo.nums;
```

You'll find it EMPTY.

So, be sure, this transaction, when interrupted, will never be committed.

> Let's say I committed 20k records and would like to begin transaction
>   for another 20k records, I would like to interrupt the transaction
>   during this second batch insertion.

You are free to do so, if you want more time to be able to interrupt your code, just add `waitfor delay`:

```
begin tran
    insert into dbo.nums 
    select row_number() over (order by getdate()) as n
    from sys.columns c1 cross join sys.columns c2 cross join sys.columns c3;

    waitfor delay '00:01:00';
```

...And be sure it will not be committed.

Answer (score 0):

If yo need to make sure when you interrupt the transaction, it doesn't end up being committed to the database.you need to use :

```
  SET XACT_ABORT { ON | OFF }
```

this will basically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error

Check the link for more info

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017